# How to write Text to Driver Console - C# - Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I try to write some own Lines of Text additional to the Driver-Console.

I mean the black console or shell that the driver itself opens up.
For example there will be written something like this just for opening the driver:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 103.0.5060.53 (a1711811edd74ff1cf2150f36ffa3b0dae40b17f-refs/branch-heads/5060@{#853}) on port 50582
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50589/devtools/browser/dea3e5d2-d992-489f-bb12-ed43fe480dc7
[1660757042.100][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 104.
[5284:21080:0817/192404.062:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [19:24:04.054] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Ein an das System angeschlossenes GerΣt funktioniert nicht. (0x1F)
[5284:8932:0817/192501.874:ERROR:util.cc(127)] Can't create base directory: C:\Program Files\Google\GoogleUpdater
[1352:14240:0817/192601.882:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(486)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

All what i have found would not work.
Here is an example:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("My own Text here");
```

I am useing C# and want to write some Text to that console / shell of the driver.

Is there any possible way to do that?

Edit #1: I am working with an Forms-Application if this is important.

Comment: Do you really need to do this, or are you just trying to see logging messages in real time? Perhaps you could write out to a file and `get-content output.txt -wait` in powershell.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. But i really want to do it.
In my case I have more than 100 Tests at the same time with different Browsers.
If something goes wrong it will be fine to identify the driver-console manually and close it manually.
But this will only possible, if i can write an identifier into it!

Comment: Have you tried `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(...)`, `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(...)`, etc?

Comment: Yes i have testet it.
Your line with Debug only work on debugging, the Trace works on degugging and release mode. But both only out of Visual Studio and reports in Studio ...
That is not what i am looking for.

I want to write into the driver-console (the black command line shell) without useing Visual Studio.

Maybe this is not possible.
But thank you so much for your try and help.